# Convergence of pdf's a.e. implies weak convergence and the converse is false

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If pdf is bounded I can use dominated convergence and we are done. But I can take pdf to be e.g. $f(x)=\mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac14]} \frac1{\sqrt{x}}$ this is not bounded and it is pdf of some distribution. So how should I approach this problem other way?

When it comes to the counter example for the converse I really could not come up with anything good.

Update: I think I know how to prove it. Let $f_n$ be our sequence of pdf's and let $f$ be its limit. For sufficiently large n $|f_n-f|$ is bounded whence we can use dominated convergence theorem to prove its integral is zero and then we can use Schaffe Lemma. To get the convergence of CDF's.

I still cannot find the counter example for the converse though.

Comment: Convergence of pdf's in what sense?

Comment: @KaboMurphy  almost everywhere, and I guess point wise

Comment: Why is $|f_n-f|$ bounded for sufficiently large $n$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample:
$$
f_{X_n}(x)=(1-\cos(2n\pi x))1_{[0,1]}(x).
$$